# How is a reed switch used to charge/discharge a capacitor?

Tags: capacitance

Ok, so there's no way to disguise this; I admit this is a question I've been set for homework but I can't find a full answer to.

I know that, in brief, a reed switch consists of two metal contacts inside a glass tube and can be operated by a magnetic field, and I've seen lots of experiments involving capacitors and reed switches (most of which also involve a signal generator), but I cannot seem to find any explanations.

Could somebody explain to me how you can charge and discharge a capacitor using a reed switch and the physics behind it please?

*By the way, I am studying Physics at A2 level.*

Comment: Would [electronics.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: @Qmechanic Quite possibly. I just immediately jumped to physics because it is the subject I'm doing but electrical engineering would probably be more appropriate. How can I move the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To charge the capacitor, a normally open reed switch is interposed between a voltage source and the capacitor, then the reed switch is exposed to a magnetic field of sufficient intensity that it causes the contacts to attract each other until they touch, allowing charge to flow from the voltage source, through the made contacts, and into the capacitor.

Once the capacitor is charged, the magnetic field can be removed, allowing the contacts to open and the charge in the capacitor to remain there.

In order to discharge the capacitor, the voltage source is removed and replaced with a load of some kind, the reed switch energized once again by the magnetic field and, when the contacts make, the charge stored in the capacitor will flow into the load, discharging the capacitor.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think this is what my tutor was looking for, although I kind of expected it to be more "automated" I guess. What advantage does a reed switch give in this situation over a more standard circuit?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by: "a more standard circuit."

Comment: I mean a circuit with just a standard switch or one where you physically connect and disconnect wires to charge and discharge a capacitor

Comment: At the most basic level, none.

Comment: What about at a more advanced level? Or do you think I should let my tutor teach me this?

Comment: If you have a question relating to a more advanced level, then you should post it as a _bona fide_ question instead of